# chaining FormGroupControl to FirebaseObjectObservable

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

It is a good idea to directly connect an angular `FormGroupControl` to `FirebaseObjectObservable`, being that they are both RxJS `Observable` objects?

I am not sure exactly what function I would use for that, because I am new to Reactive, Angular, and bDb, but it seems that would be in the scope of Obserables.

This way, as soon as you make a change in the form, it is propogated to all Firebase users who see it updated live, and as soon as someone changes it on the firebase, you will immediately see it in the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way, you may need to add customizations:

```
this.form.valueChanges
        .subscribe(this.svc.save);
this.svc.get(this.key)
       .subscribe((val)=>this.form.setValue(val, {emitEvent: false}));
```